# Deploying .war-s on Tomcat give 404 error

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

I set up a Tomcat 9 server. I pointed the HOME location in catalina.bat to the correct Java jdk folder. Then I tried to deploy some .war files in the webapps directory. The manager page reports that the files are deployed successfully but when I try to open the pages they all give a 404 error. I have no idea why despite searching google and this site. The deployed .war files are created based on tutorials found by googling or by downloading examples from Github. For example:

https://github.com/sndpchatterjee07/FileUpload
https://github.com/furkanertas/Secure-File-Uploading
https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/08/file-upload-example-in-servlet-and-jsp.html

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: What's the exact content of your web.xml and the URL you invoke in your browser? Do apache tomcats' examples work under /examples/ ? Can you verify the welcome file is correctly placed within the .war?

Comment: For the javacodegeeks example, the web.xml file is copied exactly from the tutorial:

Comment: I accidentally deleted the examples folder from webapps some time ago so I can't test those. 
web.xml is under src/main/webapp/WEB-INF
index.jsp and result.jsp are under src/main/webapp

Comment: Have you tried to deploy artifacts manually?

Comment: I've tried copying the .war files into the webapps directory and then starting the Tomcat server. I've also tried starting the server and on the manager page selecting the .war file and clicking deploy.